# Checkbox states change after navigating to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I am trying to persist the checkbox states after user traverse to another page on my rails web site.

Currently, when i navigate from index page to another page and come back to the index page checkboxes from index page get checked. I want it to hold the values I give even if I navigate to another page.

I have written

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Fixing the Turbolinks issue in rails with 'ready page:load'
    $(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
function addingChecks() {
    var filterStatusArr = [];
    filterStatusArr = localStorage.filterStatus;
    $('#filterText h4 .onoffswitch .onoffswitch-checkbox').each(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < filterStatusArr.length; ++i) {
            if (filterStatusArr[i] == "true") {
                $(this).prop('checked', true);
            } else {
                $(this).prop('checked', false);
            }
        }
    });
};

rememberFilterState();
addingChecks();
function rememberFilterState() {

    filterStatus = [];
    $('#filterText h4 .onoffswitch .onoffswitch-checkbox').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            filterStatus.push("true");
        } else {
            filterStatus.push("false");
        }
        localStorage.input = filterStatus;
    });
    //alert(filterStatus);
}
```

Works well onload but this ignores when I go to another page and come back.

Is this the approved behavior? 
How can I fix this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You are storing values into `localStorage.input` inside *rememberFilterState*, but getting them back from `localStorage.filterStatus` in *addingChecks*,

Notice, localStorage stores in json format, you have to use `JSON.stringify` when setting, and `JSON.parse` when getting value

Take a look at more optimized snippet below

```
function addingChecks() {
    if(!localStorage.filterStatus) {
        return;
    } else {
        var filterStatusArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.filterStatus);
        $('#filterText h4 .onoffswitch .onoffswitch-checkbox').each(function(index){
            $(this).val(filterStatusArr[index]);
        });
    }
};

function rememberFilterState() {
    var filterStatus = [];
    $('#filterText h4 .onoffswitch .onoffswitch-checkbox').each(function() {
        filterStatus.push($(this).val());
    });
    localStorage.filterStatus = JSON.stringify(filterStatus);
}

$(document).ready(addingChecks);
$(window).unload(rememberFilterState);
```

Comment: The function works as expected but I want it to work when I redirect from another page...

Comment: Checkout update, create a simple demo, so i can make better answer for you

Comment: //Fixing the Turbolinks issue in rails with 'ready page:load'
 $(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
I have the above line to deal with turbo link